# Checking object equality in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, bdd, jasmine, object-comparison

[Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) has built-in matchers `toBe` and `toEqual`. If I have an object like this:

```
function Money(amount, currency){
    this.amount = amount;
    this.currency = currency;

    this.sum = function (money){
        return new Money(200, "USD");
    }
}
```

and try to compare `new Money(200, "USD")` and the result of sum, these built-in matchers will not work as expected. I have managed to implement a work-around based on a custom [`equals` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) and custom matcher, but it just seems to much work.

What is the standard way to compare objects in Jasmine?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and found an existing way to do so without any custom code or matchers. Use `toEqual()`.

Answer (score 74):

If you're looking to compare partial objects, you might consider:

```
describe("jasmine.objectContaining", function() {
  var foo;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      bar: "baz"
    };
  });

  it("matches objects with the expect key/value pairs", function() {
    expect(foo).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
      bar: "baz"
    }));
  });
});
```

cf. [jasmine.github.io/partial-matching](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Partial_Matching_with_<code>jasmine.objectContaining</code>)

Answer (score 3):

Its the expected behavior, as two instances of an object are not the same in JavaScript.

```
function Money(amount, currency){
  this.amount = amount;
  this.currency = currency;

  this.sum = function (money){
    return new Money(200, "USD");
  }
}

var a = new Money(200, "USD")
var b = a.sum();

console.log(a == b) //false
console.log(a === b) //false
```

For a clean test you should write your own matcher that compares `amount` and `currency`:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.addMatchers({
    sameAmountOfMoney: function(expected) {
      return this.actual.currency == expected.currency && this.actual.amount == expected.amount;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that lodash _.isEqual is good for that

```
expect(_.isEqual(result, expectedResult)).toBeTruthy()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compare two objects without any custom code via :

```
import { deepStrictEqual } from 'assert'
// ...
expect(deepStrictEqual.bind(null, objectA, objectB)).not.toThrow()
```

note : `assert` is a native node module, no need to install anything here

Answer (score -5):

Your problem is with truthyness. You are trying to compare two different instances of an object which is true for regular equality ( a == b ) but not true for strict equality ( a === b). The comparator that jasmine uses is 
[jasmine.Env.equals_()](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/e09fd4093302b63776af14ade7e56e5442e2c693/src/core/Env.js#L394) which looks for strict equality.

To accomplish what you need without changing your code you can use the regular equality by checking for truthyness with something a little like the following:

```
expect(money1.sum() == money2.sum()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: What you said about `==` and `===` is completely wrong. Two different instances of an object with the same content will both return false. For any non-primitives, `==` and `===` behave identically. http://jsfiddle.net/9mrmyrs6/

Comment: @JuanMendes check out the answer by Andreas K. ... you guys are saying two different things. Is this a difference in newing up an object vs an object literal?

Comment: @pherris mmm....yes we are saying different things: I'm saying that when comparing non-primitives, it doesn't matter whether you use `==` or  `===`, there is no coercion involved. Andreas is saying that you can create a custom matcher. The last statement on how to fix this problem is "correct" but the explanation in the first paragraph is just incorrect. `jasmine` will actually check object contents if you use `toBe()` instead of `equals`

Comment: `a == b` will still give false if `a` and `b` are different instances, you might want to edit your answer