# Karma/Jasmine spec -- Expected { } to equal { }

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm running a Karma spec to test the functionality of an Angular BaseClass for my models that is outlined in an Egghead.io tutorial.

The behavior seems to be working, but I'm running into a weird error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) BCCache adds a cache to the model FAILED
  Expected {  } to equal {  }.
  Error: Expected {  } to equal {  }.
```

[What I could find of this error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jasmine-js/INma5VrV2Xs) (it's hard to search, given the characters -- suggests that `toEqual` should be able to recognize the two objects' equivalence -- so I'm a little stumped.

Here's the spec code (coffeescript) :

```
describe 'BCCache', ->
  it "adds a cache to the model", ->
    expect(Post.cached).toEqual({})
```

And here's what it's testing:

**base.coffee**

```
angular.module("BaseClass")
  .factory "BCBase", ['BCCache', (Cache) ->
    Base = (attributes) ->
      _constructor = this
      _prototype = _constructor.prototype

      _constructor.cached = new Cache()

    return Base
  ]
```

**cache.coffee**

```
angular.module('BaseClass')
  .factory 'BCCache', -> 
    Cache = ->    
    return Cache
```

The spec is basically asserting that the `cached` method (currently) returns a new empty object, which the `cache.coffee` file seems to successfully do. But somehow, Karma doesn't see the two empty objects as equivalent. Any idea why? I'm a little stumped.

Comment: 2 objects are equal only if their references are same.

Comment: @PSL This is not a dupe, this is a Jasmine issue.  `toEqual` should work in this instance: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jasmine-js/INma5VrV2Xs

Comment: @SomeKittens That is why i did not mark the question as duplicate, but this is missing concept.. the concept in the question is a duplicate of the above. How to get around that is another part of the question.

Comment: @PSL No, it's not.  `toEqual` is NOT `===`.  It iterates through an object and checks the properties.

Comment: OP: Can you provide a complete example in a Plunkr?  (as well as using regular JavaScript)?

Comment: @SomeKittens, example:- `expect(new Cache()).toEqual(new Cache());` is true but `expect(new Cache()).toEqual({});` is false.. You dont need a complete example for that.

Comment: Thanks, guys. So I looked into this (followed @PSL's link), and a) my attempt with lodash (`expect( _.isEqual(Post.cached, {}) ).toBe(true)`) also failed, and b) it looks like `isEqual()` [should do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401237/checking-object-equality-in-jasmine). Is there no easier way to compute object equality in Jasmine?

Comment: @Sasha Because first object's costructor is `Cache` and second ones is not. SO it fails the expectation. `var aCtor = a.constructor, bCtor = b.constructor;
      if (aCtor !== bCtor && !(isFunction(aCtor) && (aCtor instanceof aCtor) &&
        isFunction(bCtor) && (bCtor instanceof bCtor))) {
        return false;
      }`. So set your comparison to `expect(Post.cached).toEqual(new Cache())`

Comment: so @SomeKittens your 3 votes comment is wrong as i told before.. I don't think it is an issue with jasmine as well. It is clearly commented in jasmine codebase `// Objects with different constructors are not equivalent, but `Object`s
      // from different frames are.`

Comment: @PSL heh - good work proving that the issue lies with Jasmine all along (which is what my comment states)

Comment: To add to @PSLs answer, the source of equals https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js shows the behavior being described. Check line 143. Note that if you had `expect({}).toEqual({})` that would work. It's the error message that is a little misleading.

Comment: @SomeKittens i do not know why you think it is an issue. You could do `expect(Post.cached).toEqual(new Cache())` no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Post.cached` is an instance of `Cache`, while your `{}` is just a boring ol' `Object`.  Jasmine considers having a different constructor a valid reason to fail a `toEquals` comparison.

If you want to check equality as above, you can do something like:

```
var mockCache = new Cache();
expect(Post.cached).toEqual(mockCache);
```

Alternatively, you could just check if it's an empty object:

```
expect(Object.keys(Post.cached).length).toBe(0);
```

Thanks to Jeff Storey for the link to the code: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js#L143

Comment: @PSL Yep, turns out the issue was a misunderstanding of Jasmine's `toEqual` all along.

Comment: That is what i commented in the question, way back your answer.. :D, probably i could have answered without commenting and clarifying.. lol.. huff it is a competitive environment.. :D

Comment: Thanks everybody! That's an interesting one.

Comment: @sasha Yeah pretty much. But I think this should have been answered by jeff storey or myself...  since instead of arguing jasmine is wrong we investigated and pasted relevant parts that led to the answer.